# Nginx forward every request to apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, dynamic, nginx, subdomain, instance

So I have a basic setup. I have 1 main domain called domain.com. underneath it are 3 subdomains. sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com and sub3.domain.com. Now i would like to forward every request to tomcat, but I have a vhost setup where the subdomains are dynamic. So when I forward requests to tomcat sub1.domain.com can access apps from sub2.domain.com since they both run on the same tomcat instance. Is it possible to dynamically pass this. i.e. when I add a new subdomain will it be automatically seperated from the other tomcat instances and will it be able to get its own tomcat instance?

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     *.domain.com;
    root            /var/www/$host;
    index           index.php index.html index.htm;

    include         error_pages;
    include         php_config;

            location /backend {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

   if (-e /var/www/$host/ssl/$host) {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

}
```

I also have an https server block but that doesn't matter at the moment. On a second note I get a 404 when I try to access the backend what can I do to fix that? So that when I go to sub1.domain.com/backend I get the tomcat interface?

I made some changes to my nginx.conf file and I got rid of the Tomcat 404 page and I can see that Tomcat is working... well kind of. I can read text but that's it. No graphical interface no pictures just text and links. This is what my config file looks like.

```
#DOMAIN.COM

upstream backend {
        server          localhost:8080;
}

server {
    listen          80 default;
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     www.domain.com domain.com;
    root            /var/www;
    index           index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate certificates/klant.nl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key certificates/klant.nl.key;

    include         error_pages;
    include         php_config;

    location /backend {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://backend/;
    }
}
```

I know what went wrong... feel pretty stupid. I should've navigated to domain.com/backend/ instead of domain.com/backend.

Comment: do you define the new subdomains in tomcat ?

Comment: No, I never worked with tomcat before so I'm a bit anxious with editing config files and the like. I basically create the docroot for the new subdomain and then it should work instantly. At least that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: The problem here wouldn't be in nginx, cause nginx would forward the whole thing as it is to tomcat, then tomcat should somehow figure out which website this is, I'm afraid I haven't used tomcat before so I can't help past the nginx config, they seem good enough, but I don't think you need to include `php_config` or use `index.php` as an index if it's a java website, also fix the typo @ `$proxy_add_x_forwar$`

Comment: I want to use a mix of php and java on this website. So when I go to sub1.domain.com/backend then I will be forwarded to tomcat. And that typo isn't really a typo. I use nano and when i copied it it copied the $ and not what was behind it

Answer (score 0):

If Tomcat doesn't care about the target hostname, then map all requests for all domains to Tomcat and just use a single `<Host>` in Tomcat set as the `defaultHost` of the `<Engine>`.

This is how Tomcat comes configured by default: a `localhost` Host which is the default for the Engine. Any web applications deployed to that Host (those in `webapps/` by default) will respond to any request that come in, regardless of the contents of the HTTP `Host` header which normally chooses the virtual host which will handle the request.

Comment: But I still get a 404 page when I try to go to sub1.domain.com/backend. So if Tomcat doesn't really care what's in the HTTP Host header than what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Who is sending the 404: Tomcat or Nginx? If your web application is not deployed to "/backend", then weird things are going to happen.

Comment: Tomcat gives the 404. I don't really know how it all works with Tomcat yet.